# Facebook login showing error: "An error occured. Please try again later"

Tags: facebook

I am working on my website and I just added Facebook login. I asked my friend to test it, but when he tries it, it gives him the error message that says "An error occured. Please try again later."

However, when I tried to login myself with my own Facebook account, I was able to register successfully. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

Can someone test the Facebook login and tell me if its working? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do you run the App in Sandbox Mode?
If so, be sure you have give your friend the required permissions,
go to your App settings and check the Roles of your friend.

Answer (score 2):

If you want us to test the one on your site, we will need the address.

Comment: but presently we are not hosted it.it is developing site

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are debugging from http://localhost? This happened to me as well. However facebook only accepts login requests with a proper referrer, the one you provided at the application settings for your facebook app. To fix this, an easy way is to put the domain name in your hosts-file and point it to 127.0.0.1 and then develop using that host.

So if you put mydomain.com as the apps domain in facebook, open up your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts if you're on windows) and add the following line to the end of the file:

```
mydomain.com 127.0.0.1
```

Then make sure your app responds to that host name and browse to it in your browser. Now you can develop locally using mydomain.com and your facebook login should work.